# Unable to print logs in default color, when no color is specified explicitly using Colorama

Tags: python, logging, colorama

I am trying to get colored logs using colorama and logging module in python.
If I am not giving any color then it should print default terminal color, but in my logs I am getting color of previously set logs if no color is set explicitly.

Below is my setup_logging.yml file

```
import os
import yaml
import logging.config


def setup_logging(
    default_path='logging.yml', default_level=logging.INFO, env_key='LOG_CFG'):
path = os.path.join('/etc', 'module', default_path)
    value = os.getenv(env_key, None)
if value:
    path = value
if os.path.exists(path):
    with open(path, 'rt') as f:
        config = yaml.load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)
else:
    logging.basicConfig(level=default_level)
```

Logging.yml file

```
 version: 1

 disable_existing_loggers: True 


formatters:
   default:
    format:  "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - \n %(message)s"
handlers:
   console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: INFO 
    formatter: default
    stream: ext://sys.stdout

info_file_handler:
    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: default
    filename: /var/log/jsnapy/test.log
    maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
    backupCount: 20
    encoding: utf8
```

I have stripped my code for logging functions:

```
 import logging
 import colorama

class Test:

def __init__(self):
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    colorama.init(autoreset=True)
    setup_logging.setup_logging()

def testing(self):
    self.logger.debug(colorama.Fore.RED + "this is a debugging message")
    self.logger.info(colorama.Fore.BLUE+"this is an informational message")
    self.logger.warn(colorama.Fore.BLUE+"this is a warning message")
    self.logger.error(colorama.Fore.YELLOW +  "this is an error message")
    self.logger.critical("this is a critical message")

t = Test()
t.testing()
```

How to get default color in logs when no color is specified explicitly.

Comment: I am using  colorama.init(autoreset=True) to reset the color to default when nothing is specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `init(autoreset=True)` for that, as written in the official documentation:

> If you find yourself repeatedly sending reset sequences to turn off
>   color changes at the end of every print, then init(autoreset=True)
>   will automate that:

```
from colorama import init
init(autoreset=True)
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print('automatically back to default color again')
```

Comment: When I am using print then its working fine, problem occurs when I am using colorama in logs

Comment: Try to call `init(autoreset=True)` at the beginning of your script, after `import colorama` and not inside `__init__(self)`

Comment: thanks, that worked, I was using init(autoreset=True) inside __init__() function.